# How can I upload my ipod's calendar to my google calendar?

Tags: ipod, google-calendar

Unlike what Google wants me to do. I do not enter my calendar's events on my google account first, but, on my ipod's calendar first. When syncing it only dumps Google's calendar into my ipod but takes nothing from it. Any ideas or am I just messing up somehow?

Answer (score 5):

Here you go - http://www.google.co.uk/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?hl=en-uk&answer=138740

I found it with this [Google search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=ipod+google+calendar+sync).

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that your `ipod` is an `ipod touch`, as that's the only one I know of that lets you make entries in the calendar.

I'm also assuming that you have a Mac; I'm sure this is possible on windows (both iTunes and Google Sync will sync with Outlook), but I'm not familiar with how to do it.

Start by configuring iTunes to sync your iPod calendar and the iCal on your Mac; this will give you an option to pull from your iPod onto your Mac.

Next, use [Spanning Sync](http://spanningsync.com/) or [GooSync](http://www.goosync.com/) to synchronize your iCal with your Google Calendar. Either of these will let you bind your local calendar to your Google Calendar, and push the events from your iCal up to the gCal

Alternately, it may be possible in iCal to just set up the [Google Syncing](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=99358) and then mass-copy all your events to that calendar - I'm not sure.

Once you've done this, you've successfully pulled everything that used to live on your iPod into the cloud. At this point, you could have your iPod [sync directly with the cloud](http://www.google.com/sync/iphone.html); or you could leave it the way it is: iPod syncs to iCal which syncs to gCal. You can accomplish the latter with one of the sync products, or just use the native CalDav sync.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [CalDAV Calendar Sync](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?answer=151674). It is very easy to set up, and Google now provides a [settings page](https://www.google.com/calendar/iphoneselect) which allows you to select which of your calendars you want to sync to the iPhone (including external calendars which you subscribe to). After setting it up you should have two-way syncing of all your calendars.